# Adding onclick to dynamically created span tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

This seems like a trivial thing to do, but for some reason I cannot make it work.

I'm trying to highlight text inside a contenteditable div tag, using the execCommand. However, I can't use the "hiliteColor" argument, since I also want to add an onclick event to the span tag (to be able to remove the highlight again). So here's what the function looks like:

```
export function highlight(color){
  //remove any format to avoid overlap issues
  document.execCommand('removeFormat', false, null);
  //save selected text
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  //create new span around the text
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.backgroundColor = color;
  span.onclick = doSomething();  // <-------------------------------- ISSUE
  span.innerText = text;
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, span.outerHTML);
}

function doSomething(){
  alert('I was clicked!');
}
```

I tried adding the functions in several ways, including `span.addEventListener('click', () => alert('test'));`, but the onclick is never added to the span tag. Adding the style on the line above works fine.

I'm doing this in a React application if that matters.

How can I attach a function to this span? Or is there a completely different way to do the highlighting?

Thank you.

Comment: ```span.setAttribute('onclick', 'myFunction');```     #Note: - myFunction without **()**

Comment: add an Event Listener for `click` using `span.addEventListener("click", doSomething);`

Comment: @NotABot Thank you for the answer. Inspecting the html, this actually adds the onclick to the span. However, it says that my function is not defined. "doSomething is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick". EDIT: Removing the quotes around myFunction, it looks like the function is added, but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: @AbdullahAbid I tried doing this, as mentioned in the description, but it does not work for some reason.

Comment: @JesperF.  Add this ```span.setAttribute('onclick', 'myFunction()');```  with **()** it will work.

Comment: @NotABot It still says it's not defined, even though I defined it right underneath. But at least something is attached to the span now :')

Comment: @JesperF.  Is adding  like this <span onclick="doSomething()" > in you code ? Or something else is coming?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `React` i would suggest using the `React` to create and `ReactDOM` to render the element. you would import `ReactDOM` in your component like

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

and then you can create and render the element

```
let SpanElement =  React.createElement(
          "span",
          {
            style: { backgroundColor: "#0099FF"}, //Color Here
            id: "SpanID",
            className: "SpanClassName",
            onClick: () => doSomething()
          },text);


     // First Argument element to Render, Second Argument: Node to Render at
     ReactDOM.render(SpanElement, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I thought about doing something like this. But I don't know how to add it at the curser position. Using the execCommand inside this function replaces the text highligted in the browser with this element. So I can't render it at the root.

Comment: could you provide a working example through `codesandbox` or `codepen` ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I can setup a codepen with React and the modules I'm using etc. Thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect text inside `span` tag is an empty string

```js
// CASE 1
let hasText = document.createElement("span")
hasText.innerText = "I am span element"
hasText.onclick = () => console.log("clicked - text")
hasText.style.background = `red`
document.body.appendChild(hasText)

// CASE 2
let noText = document.createElement("span")
noText.onclick = () => console.log("clicked - no text")
noText.style.border = `green`
document.body.appendChild(noText)
```

Comment: This would make sense, and I see that I added the onclick before the text was added. However, I tried adding default text, as well as adding it after, but it is still not added to the span. Also, when I inspect the element and/or console log it, there is text inside the span. It has the style property, but no onclick.

Comment: if you are inspecting in chrome developer tools, you won't be getting event attributes for any of the HTML elements

Comment: where are you appending the span to document body? Basically, how are you clicking span if it's not appended to document

Comment: When I call `document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, span.outerHTML);`. Which basically inserts the span that I created at the cursor position. Which (somewhat) works, since the span is created, with the right text inside it, as well as the background color style. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand